# How to wait until memory has been freed?

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a *List<>* with about 800,000 objects in it. Once I'm done with this list, I set it to *null* and then proceed with the rest of the routine.

The problem is the .NET's garbage collector does not seem to be doing its job fast enough because when after setting this list to *null*, memory usage stays the same and I get "out of memory" exceptions.

Is there a way to wait on the garbage collector to finish its job ?

Perhaps I could redesign my program so I don't load 800,000 items at once but this is for a one time running program that's not going to be use in production at all.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer by Daniel below should be a good start for your problem.  But you can also look further at the memory usage of your program by using the SOS debugging extension (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
//I have occasionally seen an extra call to GC.Collect() here
```

However, I'd really only do this as a test to see if it helps and to establish if the `GC` is the problem.

I'm assuming you have tested things in both `Debug` and `Release` modes.

As a final note, you could potentially look at changing the [GC Latency Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx).

Comment: Tested in Release mode as in Debug mode getting to that exact point after having finished with the List<> is WAYY to long...

Answer (score 1):

If absolutely necessary, you can force GC to perform a collection with:

```
GC.Collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) forces the garbage collector to run immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using List<>.Clear() as well. This zaps objects in a heatbeat and releases resources quite fast.